# executing script (to set iptables rules) over ssh blocks for 2 hours

Tags: ssh, iptables, hanging

I have a script with some iptables rules in it.  When I execute this script on another host using 'ssh', then this call blocks for approx. 2 hours.

This is the contents of the script.  The idea is to block all traffic, except ssh, http(s), icmp and broadcast udp-discovery :

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 22,80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sport 22,80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

I execute the script via this call:

```
sshpass -p <pwd> ssh root@<host> '/bin/sh -s' < script.sh
```

And most of the time (not always), this call hangs and is interrupted after 7300 sec.  I have done a s-trace.
It also seems that this only happens when setting some iptables rules, executing any other command over ssh shows no problem although the s-trace is the same, but the interrupt happens after 0,1 sec.

```
0.000092 wait4(4075588, 0x7ffd2d32bdec, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
     0.000086 pselect6(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
  7303.455216 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4075588, si_uid=1005, si_status=255, si_utime=2, si_stime=0} ---
     0.000332 rt_sigreturn({mask=[CHLD]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
     0.000328 wait4(4075588, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 255}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 4075588
     0.000423 exit_group(255)           = ?
     0.000645 +++ exited with 255 +++
```

The strange thing is also that the iptables rules are correctly set after 7300 seconds, BUT an extra rule is added: `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere` for the INPUT and OUTPUT chains.

Can someone give some explanation about this behaviour ?

Thx

Comment: The is absolutely no guarantee that all the iptables commands will be transferred and executed. Imagine that the script is transmitted in two packets and the split is after `iptables -P FORWARD DROP` - what do you think will happen?

Comment: So the reason might be the same as described in https://serverfault.com/questions/105515/iptables-causing-ssh-to-stall

Comment: Oh yeah - you need more ICMP types allowed too. Don't send line-by-line to remote SSH shell as it will never be reliable. Save script somewhere on the remote side and execute it as one command.