# ICMP destination unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, udp, ip

I am working on an arch linux machine with ethernet interface eth1. I have created interface eth1:0 using ifconfig and given it a dummy hw address (00:01:02:03:04:05). When I send a UDP packet to a server application running on a remote server machine, I get back the right response. But then I see ICMP Destination Unreachable going out from the eth1:0 interface ip address. How can I mute this ICMP message? I have tried different mac addresses, setup arp cache on both client and server machines without success.

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder that you set an hw address to the additional interface. Are you aware, that the mac adresses started with 00:01:02 used by 3COM? (http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt)

Why you need an additional mac address?

To answer your question: Don't mute icmp responses but fix the problem or explain what you try to acomplish.

Comment: As I said I have also tried to use the interface hw address for alias interface but without success. Appreciate any help in fixing this.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I would like to get rid of the ICMP messages.

Comment: Then open the destination.

Comment: The local machine is sending the ICMP message to the remote server since it is unable to send the message received from the remote server to the port of the aliased IP address. How do "open" this port? Or how will the message from remote server reach the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sort of in the same boat with others here. Its better to track down and fix the root cause. To open the port isn't it a case of simply writing the correct firewall/IPTables rule? If you just want to blow ICMP outgoing, this thread should give you a good idea,

[Why not block ICMP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84963/why-not-block-icmp)