# Windows Server 2003 Outbound ftp Very Slow with Windows Firewall enabled

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall, ftp, upload

From Windows Server 2003, I'm uploading a file (~50MB) every day at 4:00am to my hosting space in the cloud. I'm doing it by calling "ftp -s:" in a batch file that a Scheduled Task runs.

I did what Edward suggested in the post below and watched Process Monitor while uploading:
[FTP Transfer Very Slow When Windows Firewall Enabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/353286/ftp-transfer-very-slow-when-windows-firewall-enabled)

When Windows Firewall is on, alg.exe and ftp.exe are involved at the beginning, and do quite a lot of what appears to be handshaking. Then finally only ftp.exe gets going with the send, and each event (each line in Process Monitor) appears about once a second, and has a size of 65535. The upload takes about 10 minutes.

When Windows Firewall is off, alg.exe never shows up. ftp.exe seems to start sending almost immediately, after the first 3 events/lines or so. Then the events/lines in Process Monitor appear very fast and also have a size of 65535. The upload takes about 1 min 20 secs.

Also thought I'd add that I tried this same thing using copy/paste in Windows Explorer. With firewall on or off, the upload takes about 10 minutes. The events/lines in Process Monitor appear pretty fast, but all of them only have a size of 4096.

Any ideas how to get the faster upload speed with Windows Firewall on?

Comment: Just a reminder: Windows Server 2003 is going end of extended support in about a year (august 2015), you should start to plan to replace it

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have no choice right now but to use Server 2003, but I'd wager my problem would apply in any existing Windows Server version. BTW the forum wouldn't let specify more keywords since I'm a noob).

Comment: It's not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A style site. :)

Comment: Then with all due respect, was your reply an answer?

Comment: No, this is why I posted it as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: So I assume that means my "Yes, thanks. I have no choice...." comment is like yours and is not a Q or an A.

Comment: I was merly commenting on your "BTW the forum wouldn't let specify more keywords since I'm a noob)." comment, nothing else

Comment: Wow, I guess I'll try another soup place.